# Can I directly place the call without showing that confirmation on my windows phone 8 app - (Call or Don't Call)?

Tags: c#, windows, c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

This is my code snippet:

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        PhoneCallTask task = new PhoneCallTask();
        task.PhoneNumber = "0800000000000";
        task.DisplayName = "mum";
        task.Show();

    }
```

and then I get this:

```
Dial mum at 080000000000000?
call   don't call
```

How can I make the phone call directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can't do that. It's done this way for security reasons!

Comment: is there any other approach I can use @dimitris? your help would be very appreciated.

Comment: @mendez7 No, you can't do something else. This is the only way Microsoft provides a mechanism for making phone calls / sending sms / email.

For security reasons they want the user to have the last word before doing an action like this

Comment: @mendez7 Think about this, what if you used a app on your phone which could do that (make calls without asking you) then it started repeatedly calling and hanging up a [Premium Rate Telephone number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premium-rate_telephone_number) that I own. In a few minutes you could have had hundreds of dollars of charges without you knowing it.